# Two processes. Expected value.

Tags: probability

On a computer running two processes $ X_1, X_2 $ at the same moment.
$ X_1,  X_2$ mean time work processes, respectively.

$ X_1, X_2 $ have exponential distribution. $$ E (X_1) = E (X_2) = 60s.$$
Let $T$ denotes the time of this process, which worked longer. Calculate $ E (T) $

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/146973/expected-value-of-the-maximum-of-two-exponentially-distributed-random-variables

Comment: Just noticed that after I posted an answer!  Ah well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: $T=\max\{X_1,X_2\}$. So it would be wise to first deduce the distribution of $T$ and then obtain the expectation of $T$. Notice that $X_1,X_2$ are independent with exponential parameter $\dfrac{1}{60}$. Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 1):

Approach to solution: First, determine the CDF of the needed exponential distributions

$$
F(x) \equiv P(X_i < x), \qquad i = 1, 2
$$

You will need to figure out the actual formula for $F(x)$; the above is only its definition.  Now, determine $G(x) \equiv P(T < x)$ for any $x$, the CDF of the maximum of $X_1$ and $X_2$.  Note that $G(x) = P(X_1, X_2 < x)$, $X_1$ and $X_2$ are independent, and $P(X_i > x) = 1-P(X_i < x) = 1-F(x)$.

Given any CDF $G(x)$, one can determine the average as

$$
E(T) = \int_{x=0}^\infty [1-G(x)] \, dx
$$