# Show equal distribution of the max and average of two exponential i.i.d.s

Tags: probability, probability-theory, convolution, characteristic-functions

I've been trying to prove: $Z \overset{d}{=} W$

Where:

- $Z = \frac{X+Y}{2}$,
- $W = \max(X,Y)$,
- X and Y are independent and identically exponantially distributed r.v:s with $\lambda = 1$

My idea was to calculate and compare the characteristic functions. For $Z$ we can derive its c.f., $\gamma_Z(t)$, quite easily by the following:

- $\gamma_Z(t)=\gamma_{X+Y}(\frac{t}{2}) = (\gamma_{X}(\frac{t}{2}))^2 = \frac{1}{(1-it/2)^2}\hspace{15mm}$   (1)

which is the c.f. of a $\Gamma(2,2)$-distributed r.v. While the c.f. of $W$ is harder to derive. Using the answer to this question:

- https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/18433/how-do-you-calculate-the-probability-density-function-of-the-maximum-of-a-sample

First we can see that the c.d.f. of $W$ is:

- $F_W(w) = F_X(w)F_Y(w) = (1 - e^{-w})^2 = 1 - 2e^{-w} + e^{-2w}$

And by deriving it w.r.t. $w$ we get:

- $f_W(w) = \frac{dF_W(w)}{dw} =  2(e^{-w} - e^{-2w})$

Then:

- $\gamma_W(t) = E[e^{itw}] = \int_0^{\inf}e^{itw}f_W(w)dw =   2\int_0^{\inf}e^{itw}(e^{-w} - e^{-2w})dw$
- ... $\hspace{8mm}= 2\int_0^{\inf}e^{-w(1-it)} - e^{-w(2-it)}dw $
- ... $\hspace{8mm}= 2[\frac{e^{-w(1-it)}}{it-1} - \frac{e^{-w(2-it)}}{it-2}]_0^{\inf} $
- ... $\hspace{8mm}= 2[0 - (\frac{1}{it-1} - \frac{1}{it-2})] $
- $\gamma_W(t) =  \frac{1}{1-3/2it-t^2/2} $

Which does not match the results in (1) and makes me doubt that my approach is the correct one to solve this problem. Any hints or corrections would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: But $Z=\frac12\min(X,Y)+\frac12\max(X,Y)\leq\frac12\max(X,Y)+\frac12\max(X,Y)=\max(X,Y)$. So we have $Z\leq W$ a.s. Doesn't that contradict that $Z$ and $W$ have the same distribution?

Comment: @drhab: though $Z\leq W$ does not quite contradict $Z$ and $W$ having the same distribution, since you could have $Z=W$.  But  $Z\lt W$ almost surely does lead to a contradiction

Comment: @Henry Of course. My question was meant as a stimulus to think about it in this context where it demands that $X=Y$ a.s.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result you've stated is actually false, and @drhab gave a fantastic quick argument as to why.

My best guess as to what's going on is that you may have mis-copied the question. Is it possible that $Z$ should be $X + \frac Y 2$ instead? *That* variable has the same distribution as $\max\{X, Y\}$, and a good explanation for why can be found [here](https://ckrao.wordpress.com/2011/04/17/the-maximum-of-two-exponential-random-variables/) (copied below).

> \begin{align} {\rm Pr}(X + Y/2 \leq a) &= \int_0^a e^{-x} {\rm Pr}\left(Y \leq 2(a-x)\right)\ dx\\&=\int_0^a e^{-x} \left(1-e^{-2(a-x)}\right)\ dx\\&= \int_0^a e^{-x}\ dx - e^{-2a}\int_0^a e^x\ dx\\& =  1 - e^{-a} - e^{-2a}(e^a-1)\\ &= 1 - 2e^{-a} + e^{-2a}\\&= \left(1-e^{-a}\right)^2\\ &= {\rm Pr}(X \leq a, Y \leq a)\\&= {\rm Pr}(\max\{X , Y\} \leq a)\end{align}

Comment: I hope you don't mind that I copied the argument in your link to make your answer more self contained.

Answer (score 0):

They are not equally distributed since $\mathbb{E} Z = 1$ and $\mathbb{E}W=1+1+\tfrac{1}{2} = \tfrac{3}{2}$, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/370292) why.

Comment: It is true for $Z = (X+Y)/2$ and $W=\min(X,Y)$ though.

Comment: The identity does not hold for the min case either.

Comment: You're right, I was confusing equal in expectation with equal in distribution.

Comment: @Yannik They have different expectations, don't they? $\mathbf{E}[\min(X,Y)] = \frac{1}{\lambda + \eta} = \frac12$.