# expected time for happening the first events of three independent Poisson random variables

Tags: stochastic-processes, random-variables, poisson-distribution, expected-value

suppose we have three independent Poisson random variables $X_1$ and $X_2$ and $X_3$ with the same $\lambda$. We want to have the expected time we need to wait so all of three of them be more than zero ($ X_1, X_2, X_3 > 0 $). What is the solution?

> $T^k_x$ = the random variable of wait time to see the kth event on random variable X

P.S: I did this: $P(T^1_{X_1} > t) = e^{-\lambda t}$ and three of them are the same and independent so $P(T^1_{all} > t) = P(T^1_{X_1} > t) \times  P(T^2_{X_1} > t) \times  P(T^3_{X_1} > t) = e^{-\lambda t} \times e^{-\lambda t} \times e^{-\lambda t} = e^{-3\lambda t}$ but the problem is expected of this is $\frac{1}{3\lambda}$ wich is lower than $\frac{1}{\lambda}$ so it is wrong! the expected time to have all three > 0 must be bigger that just one > 0. What is my mistake?

thanks in advance.

Comment: Your mistake is that what you calculated is (correctly) the expression for "any of them more than zero".

Comment: @LeeDavidChungLin Why "any of them?" I multiply them. that doesn't mean "all of them together?"

Comment: @LeeDavidChungLin sorry I just ask how I aks my friends when I'm confused so much. I'll edit it.

Comment: I'm a beginner so I could be wrong... if $X_1$ is a Poisson RVs then the wait time until the first event (that is $X_1$ is more than zero) is an exponential RV, call it $Y_1$, so you are looking for $E[\max(Y_1,Y_2,Y_3)]$ and you can leverage this answer https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/146973/expected-value-of-the-maximum-of-two-exponentially-distributed-random-variables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Denote the random variable $T_i$ as the waiting time length for $X_i$ to "be more than zero".

\begin{align}
&\phantom{{}={}}P(~ \text{all three more than zero before}~t~) \\
&= P(~ T_1 < t~~\&~~T_2 < t~~\&~~T_3 < t) \\
&= P(~ T_1 < t~) \cdot P(~T_2 < t~)\cdot P(~T_3 < t) \qquad \because X_i \quad \text{mutually independent}\\
&= \left( 1 - e^{-\lambda_1 t} \right)\left( 1 - e^{-\lambda_2 t} \right)\left( 1 - e^{-\lambda_3 t} \right) \\
&= \left( 1 - e^{-\lambda t} \right)^3
\end{align}

That is your desired probability. Note that this does NOT take the form of an exponential distribution.

The keyword you should be looking for is [order statistics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_statistic). Here you are dealing with the **maximum** of a set of iid exponential distribution, while your previous erroneous calculation happens to be the [minimum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_distribution#Distribution_of_the_minimum_of_exponential_random_variables).