# Exponential distribution Max(X,Y)

Tags: probability, exponential-distribution

This problem appeared in a past Quiz. I'm still not able to solve it:

Note(λ = 1/B). Suppose X~exponential(λ = 1), Y ~ exp(λ = 1) and Z ~ exp ( λ = 3)

Find P(max(X,Y) > 10) and E(max(X,Z)).

I know that for exponential distribution

max(X,Y) = min(X,Y) + R. (Where R is the remaining lifetime).

However I don't know how to use this fact to solve a problem

Comment: Do you mean $ Y \sim \mathsf{Exponential} (\lambda = {\color{red} 2} )$?

Comment: No. It's λ = 1. It has same value as X

Comment: For the first one: Pr[max(X,Y) > 10] = 1 - Pr[X<10] * Pr[Y<10]. Can you handle it from here?

Comment: Then it would be 1 - (1 - e^-10)^2 = 2e^-10 - e^-20 ?

Comment: But how can I get that result integrating directly P(max(X,Y) > 10)?

Comment: No. Pr[X<10] = integrate(0 to 1) e^(-x) dx

Comment: [See this for Q1](https://llc.stat.purdue.edu/2014/41600/notes/prob3205.pdf), [See this for Q2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/146973/expected-value-of-the-maximum-of-two-exponentially-distributed-random-variables)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\begin{align}
& \frac d {dx} \Pr( \max\{X,Z\} \le x) = \frac d {dx} \Pr(X\le x\ \&\ Z\le x) \\[10pt]
= {} & \frac d {dx} \big( (1 - e^{-x})(1-e^{-3x}) \big) = \frac d{dx}( 1 -e^{-x} - e^{-3x} + e^{-4x}) \\[8pt]
= {} & e^{-x} + 3e^{-3x} - 4e^{-4x}.
\end{align}
So look for $\displaystyle\int_0^\infty x(e^{-x} + 3e^{-3x} - 4e^{-4x}) \, dx,$ remembering that $\displaystyle\int_0^\infty xe^{cx} \, dx = \frac 1 {c^2}. $

Comment: $$
\begin{align}
& \int_0^\infty x e^{cx}\,dx \\{}\\ = {} & \frac 1 {c^2} \int_0^\infty (cx) e^{-cx} (c\,dx) \\ {} \\
= {} & \frac 1 {c^2} \int_0^\infty ue^{-u} \, du.
\end{align}$$
If that last integral is one you are very familiar with, then this substitution is the way to go. If you evaluate the last integral by parts, I'd write it as $$ \int u\big(e^{-u}\,du \big) = \int u\,dv = \cdots $$ You can just as well use integration by parts directly on the integral you started with, but it's worth knowing what $$ \int u^n e^{-u}\,du $$ is, and recognizing the present problem as an instance.