# What is the expected value of the maximum of two independent exponentially distributed random variables?

Tags: probability, random-variables, expected-value, distribution-theory, order-statistics

the density for an exponentially distributed RV X with parameter λ>0

is given as:

f(x)=(1/λ )exp(−x/λ)

for non-negative x and 0 otherwise. The expected value of the maximum of two independent exponentially distributed random variables X  and Y  with parameters λ1=1 and λ2=2  is...?

Comment: Does this help? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/146973/expected-value-of-the-maximum-of-two-exponentially-distributed-random-variables

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you need to find the Expected Value of the Maximum of a random variables it is always wise and easy to solve the problem in the following 3 steps:

1. Find the Cumulative distribution $F_M(x)$ of the maximum of the random variables
2. Differentiate this function to find the Probability Density Function $f_M(x)$
3. Find the expected value of the maximum using the formula: $\mathbb{E}[M] = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}xf_M(x)dx$

Lets do this together!

$\textbf{Step 1:}$

The cumulative density function  $F_M(x)$ is the probability that the random variable $M$ (defined to be the maximum of these 2 R.Vs) is less than $x$. I.E $F_M(x):= \mathbb{P}(M\leq x)$ In order for the maximum of the two random variables to be less than $x$ we need $\textbf{both}$ of them to be less than $x$. This should be obvious but let us just stop to think about it for a second . If we both have a dice and I roll a 4 and you roll a 6 is the maximum of our rolls less than or equal to  5? No. Why not? Because they are not $\textbf{both}$ less than 5. Hence  $ \mathbb{P}(M\leq x) = \mathbb{P}(X\leq x \cap Y\leq x) $  And as they are independent:  $ \mathbb{P}(X\leq x \cap Y\leq x)= \mathbb{P}(X \leq x) \cdot \mathbb{P}(Y \leq x)$ If you are familiar with the exponential distribution you should know that $\mathbb{P}(X \leq x) = 1 - e^{-\lambda_1 x}$ and equally  $\mathbb{P}(Y \leq x) = 1 - e^{-\lambda_2 x}$

Putting this all together completes Step $1$ and yields: $F_M(x):= \mathbb{P}(M\leq x) = \mathbb{P}(X\leq x \cap Y\leq x) = \mathbb{P}(X \leq x) \cdot \mathbb{P}(Y \leq x) = (1 - e^{-\lambda_1 x}) \cdot (1 - e^{-\lambda_2 x}) = 1 -e^{-\lambda_1x} - e^{-\lambda_2x} + e^{-(\lambda_1+\lambda_2)x}$ And using $\lambda_1 = 1$ and $\lambda_2 = 2$ yields the final CDF : $F_M(x) = (1-e^{-x}-e^{-2x}+e^{-3x})$

$\textbf{Step 2:}$

It is lightwork from here. We differentiate the CDF with to yield the PDF:

$f_M(x) = \frac{d}{dx}F_m(x) = \frac{d}{dx}(1-e^{-x}-e^{-2x}+e^{-3x}) = e^{-x} + 2e^{-2x}-3e^{-3x} $

$\textbf{Step 3:}$

We are after the expected value of $M$ (the maximum) so all we would need to do is integrate:

$\mathbb{E}[M] = \int_{0}^{+\infty}x\cdot f_M(x)dx = \int_{0}^{+\infty}x\cdot (e^{-x} + 2e^{-2x}-3e^{-3x})dx $

This is fairly easy to do via parts however I am very lazy so lets be naughty and recognise that this is the "sum" of exponential R.V's:
$ \int_{0}^{+\infty}x\cdot (e^{-x} + 2e^{-2x}-3e^{-3x})dx = \int_{0}^{\infty}x\cdot e^{-x} + \int_{0}^{\infty}x\cdot2e^{-2x} - \int_{0}^{\infty}x\cdot3e^{-3x}  $

Which we can see the simply be the calculations required to calculate the expected value of $\lambda = 1 ,  \lambda = 2, \lambda = 3$ exponential R.Vs respectively. And as the Expected value of an exponential R.V is $\frac{1}{\lambda}$ we have:
$  \int_{0}^{\infty}x\cdot e^{-x} + \int_{0}^{\infty}x\cdot2e^{-2x} - \int_{0}^{\infty}x\cdot3e^{-3x}  = \frac{1}{1} + \frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{3} = \frac{6+3-2}{6} = \frac{7}{6}$

And hence the expected value is $\frac{7}{6} = 1 + \frac{1}{6} \approx 1.167 $